# Array Allocation causing terminal to hang

Tags: c, arrays

I came across this code accidentally:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    int array[3];
    for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
        array[i]=0;
    return 0;
}
```

On running this code my terminal gets hanged - the code is not terminating.

When I replace `3` by `2` code runs successfully and terminates without a problem.
In C there is no bound checking on arrays, so what's the problem with the above code that is causing it to not terminate?

Platform - Ubuntu 10.04
Compiler - gcc

Comment: There are 4 numbers between 0 and 3. But, the array is declared to have only 3 elements.

Comment: i know that....my problem is why this code is not terminating ?

Comment: I too wonder what causes the hang. In any well-behaved system, trying to write other people's memory locations would cause an abnormal program termination, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, writing to locations between the program break, and the stack crash the program (usually). You happened to write to a valid location.

Comment: @MrLister Writing to memory owned by another process might cause an exception, depending on the system. In this case, the program is likely to be stepping on its own stack, so not accessing another process's memory.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it by putting some printf statements around the array assignment, and (at least on my system) your assumprion is correct, the assignment does overwrite i.

Comment: ya it's overwriting 'i' ...i too observed the same using gdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there's no bound checking doesn't mean that there are no consequences to writing out of bounds. Doing so invokes Undefined Behavior, so there's no telling what may happen.

This time, on this compiler, on this architecture, it happens that when you write to `array[3]`, you actually set `i` to zero, because i was positioned right after `array` on the stack.

Comment: i think you are correct...you can actually see that using gdb.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is reading beyond the bound of array and causing an **Undefined Behavior**.

When you declare an array of size `3`. The valid index range is from `0` to `2`.
While your loop runs from `0` to `3`.

If you access anything beyond the valid range of an array then it is Undefined Behavior and your program may hang or crash or show any behavior. The c standard does not mandate any specific behavior in such cases.

When you say C does not do bounds checking it actually means that it is programmers responsibility to ensure that their programs do not access beyond the beyonds of the allocated array and failing to do so results in all safe bets being off and any behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[3];
```

This declares an array of 3 ints, having indices 0, 1, and 2.

```
for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
    array[i]=0;
```

This writes *four* ints into the array, at indices 0, 1, 2, and 3. That's a problem.

Nobody here can tell exactly what you're seeing -- you haven't even specified what platform you're working on. All we can say is that the code is broken, and that leads to whatever result you're seeing. One possibility is that i is stored right after array, so you end up setting i back to 0 when you do array[3]=0;. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

The highest valid index for `array` is `2`. Writing past that index invokes undefined behaviour.

What you're seeing is a manifestation of the undefined behaviour.

Contrast this with the following two snippets, both of which are correct:

```
/* 1 */
int array[3];
for(i=0;i<3;i++) { array[i] = 0; }

/* 2 */
int array[4];
for(i=0;i<4;i++) { array[i] = 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared array of size 3 which means (0,1,2 are the valid indexes)

if you try to set 0 to some memory location which is not for us *unexpected* (generally called **UB** undefined behavior) things can happen

Answer (score 0):

The elements in an array are numbered 0 to (n-1). Your array has 3 spots, but is initializing 4 location (0, 1, 2, 3). Typically, you'd have you for loop say i < 3 so that your numbers match, but you don't go over the upper bound of the array.